# HHH90001006: Missing cache[default-update-timestamps-region] was created on-the-fly

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching, ehcache

A trivial [Spring Boot 2.5 application](https://github.com/JanStureNielsen/so-cache-demo) with Spring Data JPA with EhCache 3 and Hibernate 5 with Query and Second Level Caches enabled:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
```

generates a warning from Hibernate and an information message from EhCache for each cache on startup:

```
WARN org.hibernate.orm.cache          HHH90001006: Missing cache[default-update-timestamps-region] was created on-the-fly. The created cache will use a provider-specific default configuration: make sure you defined one. You can disable this warning by setting 'hibernate.javax.cache.missing_cache_strategy' to 'create'.
INFO org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager  Cache 'default-update-timestamps-region' created in EhcacheManager.
```

and

```
WARN org.hibernate.orm.cache          HHH90001006: Missing cache[default-query-results-region] was created on-the-fly. The created cache will use a provider-specific default configuration: make sure you defined one. You can disable this warning by setting 'hibernate.javax.cache.missing_cache_strategy' to 'create'.
INFO org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager  Cache 'default-query-results-region' created in EhcacheManager.
```

What's the proper EhCache configuration for these Hibernate caches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Disable expiration on the `default-update-timestamps-region` cache as recommended by Hibernate](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/documentation/src/main/asciidoc/userguide/chapters/caching/Caching.adoc#query-cache-regions):

```
@Configuration @EnableCaching
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public CacheManager ehCacheManager() {
        CacheManager cacheManager = Caching.getCachingProvider().getCacheManager();

        hibernateDefaultUpdateTimestampsRegionConfiguration(cacheManager);
        hibernateDefaultQueryResultsRegion(cacheManager);

        return cacheManager;
    }

    /**
     * Create Hibernate's default-update-timestamps-region cache. No expiration per Hibernate recommendation:
     * https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/documentation/src/main/asciidoc/userguide/chapters/caching/Caching.adoc#query-cache-regions
     *
     * @param cacheManager
     */
    private void hibernateDefaultUpdateTimestampsRegionConfiguration(CacheManager cacheManager) {
        CacheConfigurationBuilder<Object, Object> builder = CacheConfigurationBuilder
                .newCacheConfigurationBuilder(Object.class, Object.class,
                        ResourcePoolsBuilder.newResourcePoolsBuilder().offheap(1, MemoryUnit.MB));

        javax.cache.configuration.Configuration<Object, Object> cache = Eh107Configuration.fromEhcacheCacheConfiguration(builder);

        cacheManager.createCache("default-update-timestamps-region", cache);

        //cacheManager.createCache("default-update-timestamps-region", new MutableConfiguration<>());
    }

    /**
     * Create Hibernate's default-query-results-region cache.
     * https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/documentation/src/main/asciidoc/userguide/chapters/caching/Caching.adoc#query-cache-regions
     *
     * @param cacheManager
     */
    private void hibernateDefaultQueryResultsRegion(CacheManager cacheManager) {
        CacheConfigurationBuilder<Object, Object> builder = CacheConfigurationBuilder
                .newCacheConfigurationBuilder(Object.class, Object.class,
                        ResourcePoolsBuilder.newResourcePoolsBuilder().offheap(1, MemoryUnit.MB));

        javax.cache.configuration.Configuration<Object, Object> cache = Eh107Configuration.fromEhcacheCacheConfiguration(builder);

        cacheManager.createCache("default-query-results-region", cache);

        //cacheManager.createCache("default-query-results-region", new MutableConfiguration<>());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I find it easier to configure it in **ehcache.xml**:

```
<cache-template name="default">
    <expiry><ttl unit="minutes">60</ttl></expiry>
    <heap unit="entries">1000</heap>
</cache-template>

<cache alias="default-query-results-region">
    <expiry><ttl unit="minutes">60</ttl></expiry>
    <heap unit="entries">1000</heap>
</cache>
    
<cache alias="default-update-timestamps-region">
    <expiry><none/></expiry>
    <heap unit="entries">1000</heap>
</cache>
```

IMPORTANT: Align the query results expiration with the expiration of the entities returned by the query. Further reading [here](https://dzone.com/articles/pitfalls-hibernate-second-0) and [here](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-ehcache/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty good explanation for this: https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/integrations/hibernate.html#configure-

If you want these warnings to go away, you can define the caches explicitly in the ehcache.xml or you use the `create` configuration value as the warning logs.

Comment: I've re-written the question to be a bit more clear/direct. The question is what's the proper EhCache configuration for these Hibernate caches...so it's first a question of what Hibernate needs, then how to implement with EhCache 3.

Comment: What do you mean by proper? Just add e.g. `<cache name="default-update-timestamps-region"/>` and `<cache name="default-query-results-region"/>` to the ehcache.xml. If you want to know what values to configure, take a look at what wildfly configures for the `<cache-container name="hibernate"/>` in its `standalone-ha.xml`.

Comment: The key here is to disable expiration for the timestamp cache according to Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

***I'm sharing my complete example of Second-Level Caching.***

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/practice</property>
        <property name="connection.user">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">Welcome123#</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
        <property name="cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
        <property name="cache.ehcache.missing_cache_strategy">create</property>

        <mapping class="com.oracle.dto.BankAccount"/>
        <mapping class="com.oracle.dto.Citizen"/>



    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Bean

```
package com.oracle.dto;

import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Data
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class BankAccount {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO,generator = "bid")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "bid",sequenceName = "b_id",initialValue = 2000,allocationSize = 1)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Column(name="bank_id",updatable = false,nullable = false)
    private Long bId;
    private Integer branchCode;
    private Double accountBalance;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="account_opening_date",updatable = false,nullable = false)
    private Date accountOpeningDate;
}
```

Main Class

```
package com.oracle.main;

import com.oracle.dto.BankAccount;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class CacheDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SessionFactory sf=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session1 = sf.openSession();
        BankAccount account1 = session1.get(BankAccount.class,2000l);
        System.out.println(account1);
        session1.close();
        Session session2 = sf.openSession();
        BankAccount account2 = session2.get(BankAccount.class,2000l);
        System.out.println(account2);
        session1.close();
        sf.close();
    }
}
```